# How does self.x work if x is not a class bound or instance bound variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, class, oop

### How does `self.x` work if `x` is not a class bound or instance bound variable? In this case, is there any benefit to use it?

#### My Analysis:

In general if we execute `a.a1 = 5`, interpreter will give NameEror: name a is not defined. It means we can't define variable using letter `.`, as it is used to call attribute of an object.
If I write code as

```
a = 5
a.a1 = 10
```

It gives AttributeError: int object has no attribute `x`. It was expected.
Now look at my below code

```
class Example:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = 2
    def my_function(self):
        self.x = 5
        return self.x
obj = Example()
print(obj.my_function())
print(dir(obj), obj.__dict__)
```

As `x` is neither a class bound variable nor an instance bound variable. So I assume `x` is not an attribute of `self` but it executes successfully without any error. So I am wondering, how does it work. Please explain it, also let me know the use because as per explanation we can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `self.x = 5` you simply create a new attribute which you can later modify, just like an ordinary variable ; except you access it through the instance.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I am wondering, if there is any advantage to create new attribute over ordinary local variable as we can't use created new attribute anywhere other than the method in which we created that attribute, only we can update it like ordinary local variable. Is new attribute creation an efficient way to utilize memory?

Comment: In fact you're wrong, as the variable is reattached to the instanc, it doesn't disappear.

Comment: Thanks @FrenchMasterSword - You are right, I actually didn't use proper execution order. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

At that moment you are declaring and instantiating a new field for the object of type `Example`. When in other function, there would be reference to `self.x`, no error would be thrown. When no declaration was made - runtime error would be raised, for example:

```
class Example:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = 2
    def my_function(self):
        self.x = 5
        return self.x
    def other(self):
        return self.x
obj = Example()
print(obj.other())
print(obj.my_function())
```

This results in `AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'x'`.

One needs to bear in mind execution order, so that the field is declared and instantiated before referenced.

Comment: Thanks @Andronicus - I already tried this, you are right. But I am wondering, if there is any advantage to create new attribute over ordinary local variable as we can't use created new attribute anywhere other than the method in which we created that attribute, only we can update it like ordinary local variable. Is new attribute creation an efficient way to utilize memory?

Comment: I don't think, that there is any difference in memory utilization. What is more important for me is that field instantiation in method body makes code less readable and more error prone. Those errors would be raised depending on method invocation order, what makes them hard to find.

Comment: Thanks @Andronicus - I got it now.

Comment: No problem:)
For the future, consider marking the correct answer / upvoting, so that others know, which is the right answer.

Comment: True, I will certainly do it. Although I would say I tried to upvote few answer, but I think I am unable to do it as I don't have minimum 15 reputation.

Comment: You do have now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard way of defining attribute. Here you can find more about classes and attributes: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html